# insert in url paratmeters using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a url something like:

```
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=abc123
```

or

```
http://somewhere.com/dir/?parameter1=123123&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=abc123
```

and some variables including:

```
var alpha = aaa;
var num = 111;
var alphanum= aaa123;
```

i want to add these variables by by one into url every url parameters using javascript (or jQuery) , so that i have:

```
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=aaa&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=abc123
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=111&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=abc123
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=aaa123&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=abc123
```

and for next parameter:

```
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=aaa&parameter3=abc123
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=111&parameter3=abc123
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=aaa123&parameter3=abc123
```

and the last one

```
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=aaa
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=111
http://somewhere.com/dir/parameter1=123123&parameter2=abcabc&parameter3=aaa123
```

how can i do it ? 
thanks.

Comment: learn javascript. thanks.

Comment: well... at least show your approach.

Comment: just concatenate your variables to that url params.

Comment: Dude, it is very simple, I'm sure there's explanations in the internet. Please read Stackoverflow's guidelines on how to create a POST/Question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to encode a URI.</p>

<button onclick="clickHandler()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function clickHandler() {
     var url = "http://somewhere.com/dir/?";
     var alpha = "aaa";
     var num = 111;
     var alphanum= "aaa123";
     var params = {
       alpha,
       num,
       alphanum
     }
     var amp = '';
     for (var key in params) {
       if (!params.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
       var value = params[key];
         url += amp;
         url += encodeURI(key);
         url += '='
         url += encodeURI(value);
         amp = '&';
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To see it working click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FH0LAT6JHMP5).

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate, and shows no effort, per SO guidelines.  Please **do not answer** questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable in jQuery we use `$(YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME)` for example `$(alpha)` will output `aaa`
So here's the code needed to set up this URL:

```
var alpha = aaa;
var num = 111;
var alphanum= aaa123;

var url = "http://somewhere.com/dir/?parameter1=" + $(alpha) + "&parameter2=" + $(num) + "&parameter3=" + $(alphanum);
```

Now you could use the URL variable where you want to put the full URL such as:

```
alert($(url));
```

And the output will be:

```
http://somewhere.com/dir/?parameter1=aaa&parameter2=111&parameter3=aaa123
```

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate, and shows no effort, per SO guidelines.  Please **do not answer** questions like this.